# Why does a quoted string match bool method signature before a std::string?

Tags: c++, string, arguments, boolean

Given the following methods:

```
// Method 1
void add(const std::string& header, bool replace);

//Method 2
void add(const std::string& name, const std::string& value);
```

It would appear that the following code will end up calling method 1 instead of method 2:

```
something.add("Hello", "World");
```

I ended up creating another method that looks like this:

```
//Method 3
void MyClass::add(const char* name, const char* value) {
    add(std::string(name), std::string(value));
}
```

It worked. So it would seem that when a method accepts a "quoted string" it will match in the following order:

1. `const char*`
2. `bool`
3. `std::string`

Why would a quoted string be treated as a `bool` before a `std::string`? Is this the usual behavior? I have written a decent amount of code for this project and haven't had any other issues with the wrong method signature being selected...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My guess is the conversion from pointer to bool is an implicit primitive type conversion, where the conversion to `std::string` requires the call of a constructor and the construction of a temporary.

Comment: This is it. I had this problem once and it confused me, but your second parameter is a const char*, and that will be converted into a boolean.

Answer (score 9):

In your case you have has overloaded functions. Overloading resolution occurs according to Section 13.3.

**C++03 13.3.3.2/2:**

> When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as defined in 13.3.3.1)
>   —  a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and
>   —  a user-defined conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2) is a better conversion sequence than an ellipsis conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.3).

Conversion pointer into bool is a standard conversion. Conversion pointer into std::string is a user-defined conversion.

> **4.12 Boolean conversions**
>   An rvalue of arithmetic, enumeration, **pointer**, or pointer to member type can be converted to an rvalue of type **bool**.  A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to true.

Answer (score 6):

Pointers have an implicit conversion to `bool`. Perhaps you have seen the following:

```
void myFunc(int* a)
{
    if (a)
        ++(*a);
}
```

Now, in C++, implicit conversions between built-in types take precedence over conversions between class-types. So for example, if you had a class:

```
class Int
{
public:
    Int(int i) {}
}
```

And you overloaded a function for `long` and `Int`:

```
void test(long n) {cout << "long";}
void test(Int n) {cout << "Int";}
```

You'll see that the following code calls the long overload:

```
int i;
test(i);
```

Comment: Note that std::string is "user-defined" too, despite being a defined by the standard. I think the more appropriate term is "class type" versus "non-class type".